# How to install webilder on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: package-management, python, 16.04, desktop-background, flickr

I was trying to install my favorite background changer application on the latest Ubuntu, however I met the following Issue:

webilder : Depends: python-support (>= 0.90.0) but it is not installable

I guess the package doesn't exists in 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) any more. So how could I still install webilder? http://www.webilder.org/

Thank you!

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-support/1.0.15/+publishinghistory

The package is deleted. What would be the elegant solution for this Problem? Should I install the package simply from .deb file? Or what could be the a reason that a package is simply deleted... I dont really understand this kind of attitude of ubuntu. Simple users need a seamless solution for application installation, and backwards compatibility. This application is from 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution or a workaround:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=python-support
I picked the following ppa:
https://launchpad.net/~syseleven-platform/+archive/ubuntu/xenial-ports
and I could install python-support and webilder 0.7.3.1 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot run the application despite the successful installation. The Python error messages are so far only mystery for me. Any Idea?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/webilder_desktop", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Webilder==0.7.3', 'gui_scripts', 'webilder_desktop')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point...

Comment: So the solution for the run error:

pip install Pillow

and then:

sudo gedit /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webilder/flickr/__init__.py

from PIL import Image
#import Image

Answer (score 0):

I digged in, and found a solution:

1. As you mentioned: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:syseleven-platform/xenial-ports`
2. `sudo apt update && sudo apt install python-support python-imaging`

`python-imaging` was the last thing you needed. It is working for me now

Comment: so you don't need to modify /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webilder/flickr/__init__.py file and installing Pillow